# Code where <select> changes options in another <select>

Tags: javascript, html

I have made same code in Javascript that will change options in drop-down list of cities when user changes state.

The problem with the code is that it won't work. I think that code is OK, but I am very new in JavaScript, so I can't see the error.

Can you please check my code and see where I made error. Thanks.

JavaScript:

```
function drzava_promjena() {
    var obj_state = document.getElementById("id_drzava")
    var index = obj_states.selectedIndex;
    var value_state = obj_state.options[index].value;
    towns = town_list[value_state];
    var obj_town = document.getElementById("id_gradovi");
    while (obj_town.options.length > 0) {
        obj_town.remove(0);
    }
    var new_value;
    for (var i = 0; i < towns.length; i++) {
        new_value = document.createElement("option");
        new_value.value = towns[i];
        new_value.text = towns[i];
        try {
            obj_town.add(new_value);
        } catch (e) {
            obj_town.appendChild(new_value);
        }
    }
```

And this is HTML:

```
    <select id="id_drzava" onchange="drzava_promjena(this);">
        <option value="Austrija">Austrija</option>
        <option value="Njemacka">Njemacka</option>
        <option value="Slovenija">Slovenija</option>
        <option value="Ceska">Ceska</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="id_gradovi" onchange="">
        <option value="0"></option> 
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="id_uni" onchange="">
        <option></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483387/drop-down-menu-for-selecting-country-then-states/11483802#11483802

Comment: How about doing some basic debugging via your console? There are multiple things wrong here (e.g. typos, undefined variables).

Comment: You define `obj_state` and then try to reference `obj_states` in the next line. Where is `town_list`?

Comment: I see a few typos, not sure if they're in your actual code as well:
var index = obj_states.selectedIndex; should be obj_state
for (var i = 0; i < gradovi.length; i++) { should be towns.length

Also you should declare the towns variable in scope to prevent it from going into the global scope. "var towns = ..."

I haven't had any luck modifying selects in IE7, I've only gotten them working by creating a new select each time.

Comment: @jholloman there are some typos because I gave variable names in my native language, and when i posted question I translated on english. It seems I missed some.

Comment: @depecheSoul: Perhaps creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful in narrowing your question down to a specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. I've also [put up a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschobert/nqwv8/) to demonstrate.

JavaScript:

```
var populateCities = function (country, target_id) {
    var i = 0, options, cities, selection, target;

    cities = {
        "usa": {
            "dallas": "dal",
            "san francisco": "sf",
            "houston": "hou"
        },
        "fr": {
            "paris": "pr",
            "la riche": "lr"
        }
    };

    selection = country.options[country.selectedIndex].value;
    target = document.getElementById(target_id);
    target.options.length = 0;

    if(selection !== 'none') {
        options = cities[selection];

        for(var city in options) {
            target.options[i] = new Option(city, options[city]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}​
```

HTML:

```
<select id="country" onchange="populateCities(this, 'cities')">
    <option selected value="none">Pick a country</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
</select>
<select id="cities"></select>
```